# Can't open localhost in Microsoft Edge (Project Spartan) in Windows 10 preview

Tags: iis, browser, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I installed Windows 10 preview and installed IIS.

Open "http://localhost" in Project Spartan can't connect.

IE has no problem. What's the problem?

Comment: This might be a quirk with Spartan, seeing as it is not in a final release form. Does running `CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.Windows.Spartan_cw5n1h2txyewy` from an elevated command prompt resolve the issue?

Comment: As of build 10166, [localhost is now accessible by default in Microsoft Edge](https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/619193524991492097).

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to open http: //my-fqdn (where my-fqdn is the fully qualified domain name of my laptop). Oddly enough, http: //localhost worked fine. The accepted answer below fixed my problem, though I had to use the command-line fix. Just checking the box in about:flags did *not* fix the problem for me. (It was already checked. Unchecking, restarting, rechecking, restarting also did *not* work.)

Comment: Voting to close as No-repro as this is no longer reproducible and people for some reason are still coming here for solutions to their problems with newer versions of Windows 10.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

So the issue is <strike>Spartan</strike> Edge doesn't have access to the loopback addresses, which is something that most Windows Store apps are blocked from accessing.

If you are using Windows 10 RTM or build 10166, this can be done by navigating to `about:flags` and checking "Allow localhost loopback":

[image]

<sub><sup>Image courtesy of [Ryan Joy](https://twitter.com/atxryan/status/619213778220138496) and used [with consent](https://twitter.com/atxryan/status/619215224600662016).</sup></sub>

If you are using a previous build of Windows 10, the `CheckNetIsolation` tool can be used to add it to the LoopbackExempt list. Use this from an elevated command prompt:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

`Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe` is the identifier for the Edge app. It can be determined by using `Get-AppxPackage` in PowerShell and sifting through the results for the Spartan / Edge and using the `PackageFamilyName`.

As of Build 10158, the PackageFamilyName has changed from `Microsoft.Windows.Spartan_cw5n1h2txyewy` to `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`.

Comment: I suspect this workaround will not be required once Spartan actually ships.

Comment: I work on the Microsoft Edge team. This is a *known issue* that we are currently looking into.

Comment: Jonathan, does that mean Edge *should* have localhost access eventually? And would that localhost access work from any web page or just manually in the address bar?

Comment: Check also this thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_internet-insider_spartan/spartan-will-not-view-localhost-sites/92a0a2f0-f1ba-4ab9-a486-7fe1fa1f5b97

Comment: I am using the latest build which is 10240, try both CheckNetIsolation command but no different & I still can't access into localhost, it might be good if those who are able to connect to their localhost posting here with some screenshot

Comment: When I went into the developer settings, the "Allow localhost loopback" was already checked, and it still is not working.

Comment: Rather than 'sifting through' the PowerShell responses you can filter like so: `Get-AppxPackage | ? { $_.PackageFullName -like '*edge*' }`

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me.  The solution for me was to remove the domain name from the Trusted Sites list.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384571/why-does-microsoft-edge-open-some-local-websites-but-not-others-where-the-doma

Comment: @Sampson XAMPP localhost malfunctions on Edge precisely because it insists on prefixing the named site with `localhost`, e.g. `localhost/mysite/`, not just `mysite/`, which is the way localhost sites are accessed on every other browser. For example, I have an htaccess MOD rewrite that directs `info` to `/info.php`. Because of the `localhost/` prefix requirement, the site looks for `info.php` not in `mysite` but in the root, `localhost`, causing the site to fail. This does not happen when the site is run from as live server. What can be done to eliminate the requirement for the prefix?

Comment: @Tom I'll setup a small XAMPP project on my end to see if I can repro the issue. Can you share an example of your .htaccess file so as to ensure parity between my setup and yours?

Comment: @Sampson Please see my new entry to this thread below, as it contains detailed information on how my XAMPP server is set up. The .htaccess code in question, though, is: Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^info/?$ /info.php [L] -- This is easier to read in my response post at the bottom, because of the formatting it allows. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tom using answers to ask for clarification is likely to get your "answer" deleted. I would instead ask a new StackOverflow question all together with that text and link Jonathan to it.

Comment: @Sampson I had posted a full description of my set-up and a way to reproduce the issue on edge as a fresh response here, but one of the readers advised me to move it elsewhere. I had already started a thread on that, and so I moved my explanation there, which is here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193796/running-localhost-in-edge-browser-creates-path-confusion

Comment: I had "Allow Loopback" unchecked and this command still fixed my issue.

Comment: I unchecked the allow loopback option, restarted edge, then checked it, restarted edge again, and it worked.

Comment: @Sampson, Its almost 2018 and it still does not work.

Comment: @Sampson *I work on the Microsoft Edge team. This is a known issue that we are currently looking into. – Sampson Jun 9 '15*  Aaand 3 years later and it STILL does not work.

Comment: @Sampson, It's 2019 and it still doesn't work - what a progress huh.

Comment: @Sampson now 2020, still cannot loopback in Edge

Comment: When I enter localhost address to EDGE it opens me IE with that address, what now ? :/

Answer (score 18):

Microsoft Edge runs with network isolation by default for security reasons. To enable loopback and debug your localhost server run the following command from an elevated shell if you have **10158 or newer**:

**CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe**

or

**checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -p=S-1-15-2-3624051433-2125758914-1423191267-1740899205-1073925389-3782572162-737981194**

or this one if you have an older version

CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.Windows.Spartan_cw5n1h2txyewy

In a future update, you’ll be able to enable localhost loopback support using **about:flags**.

Comment: For anyone who is not familiar with command. Open command prompt such as **cmd** or **PowerShell** or whatever command line program for Windows and open it as administrator by right click. Enter the command from the answer above and press enter. Close all MS Edge window and re-open it. That's it.

Comment: Tried both coms as admin. Dev flag is also checked. Does not work. Pop up "You'll need an app..". Any ideas?

Comment: So wait, I can access the whole internet, but not the local host, 'for security reasons'? Seems to make no sense.... I am a developer. Accessing localhost is kinda... you know... **important**. As it does not work I just don't test on Edge. I wonder how this will work out for Edge, the browser. My guess is the inability to test with it will mean it will get little love from devs. I know I'm not going through another 'just install VMs to test your website' IE shenanigans again!

Comment: Ran into this issue on Win10 pro build 18363. So it's still a thing. Dev flags were checked. Solved it with the first command.

Answer (score 8):

For the latest build (10158), the following command did it for me:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

The trick is to use the `Get-AppxPackage` PowerShell command to find out the family name of Edge app as [vcsjones mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30334398).

Comment: I have to do `CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"` - note the quote marks around the family name

Answer (score 7):

As of Windows 10 Build 10166+ ([available today](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/07/09/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10166/) via Windows Insider), localhost access is available by default in Microsoft Edge without running the CheckNetIsolation command listed in previous answers.

You can disable this access via "about:flags", if you wish to have an even more secure configuration.

Comment: I can use 'localhost' and the official ip address on a build 10240, but unfortunately, the computer name can not be used.

Comment: It also can't access subdomains of localhost - I have each of my web projects configured as `project1.localhost:8080`, `project2.localhost:8080` etc. since I can use root relative URLs - however Edge cannot access them

Comment: Actually, when I access localhost, it works once. Then when I try to reload the page it comes up with the 'you need an app for that' message again. So testing with Edge is really inconvenient!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow to following steps:

> 1.

[image]

> 2.

Copy this code

> ```
> CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
> ```
>
> 3.

[image]

**

> Job Done!

Answer (score 0):

Add subdomain to 
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
(Windows 10)

Comment: 127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost

Comment: I have it added like that - no success.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
save hosts file copy for backup
open hosts file as administrator
delete or comment out any lines with 127.x.x.x or localhost...

restart pc.

Answer (score 0):

Neither did the `CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe` command nor manually enabling the "Allow localhost loopback" on Edge work for me.

What did work is the following:

1. Edit the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and add a mapping for a custom
       hostname to 127.0.0.1 like `127.0.0.1       local`.
2. Open Internet Options
       and add http://local to the local intranet sites.