# AJAX not working on IE Edge windows 10 Only

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, windows-10, microsoft-edge

i've an AJAX call that isn't working on IE-Edge under a certain jQuery event.

```
     $.ajax({
        url:"http://api.mysite.com/34sd418?v=1",
         success:function(result){
        }});
```

In the beginning the url was:

> //api.mysite.com/34sd418?v=1 - **without the protocol**
>
> jQuery version : code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

but both of the options not working.
On other **browsers (Chrome,FF, Other IE, Edge on WIN7) it is working**.
Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of jQuery 1.12.0. Does the problem still persist?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? Is it returning a cached response? Is there no request at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Edge blocked cross-domain requests sent to IPs in same private network CIDR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581503/microsoft-edge-blocked-cross-domain-requests-sent-to-ips-in-same-private-network)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Mine is not a cross site scripting issue. The site is running