# MS Edge <video> cross-origin subtitles fail

Tags: html5-video, cross-domain, microsoft-edge, webvtt

I have a video with WebVTT subtitles in several languages. They seem to play fine on all of our target browsers *except* for MS Edge.

The WebVTT files are served from Amazon S3 (the video is served from the same bucket), and they're marked with the correct content type (text/vtt). The files themselves are valid, and I can even get them to play in MS Edge as long as they're served from the same origin as the page containing the video.

The video tag itself is marked with `crossorigin="anonomous"`. I can't find any documentation that says anything about making cross-origin requests for the *track* resource, though. I've tried putting `crossorigin="anonymous"` on the track, too, with no luck.

The S3 bucket is set to allow cross-origin GET requests from anywhere.

Is this just broken in Edge, or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**
A link to the video is http://workbench.mercuryanalytics.com/instructions/video/no-buttons/es.html

Comment: Do you have a link to the page where the video is supposed to play? Inspecting the element live might help diagnose if this is an Edge issue or if there's a persisting CORS issue on the domain. Edge *should* work fine if everything is configured properly; it's supported CORS in every version since release.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581503/microsoft-edge-blocked-cross-domain-requests-sent-to-ips-in-same-private-network and also possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896958/xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x80070005-access-is-denied-on-microsoft-edge-bu

Comment: I've added a link to the video -- it's a little hard to get to because it's buried in an iframe, but you can see it shows the subtitles just fine on Chrome and doesn't show them on Edge.

I _don't_ think the links you offered are relevant, because I'm not doing any AJAX calls, here. This is just sticking a <track> tag inside the <video> tag and expecting the browser to do the work. The sample link I gave works if I change it to serve the titles from that server (workbench.mercuryanalytics.com), but not when I point to them on S3.

Comment: I've found out the hard way that each of the browser vendors implement the HTML5 video tag very differently. Have you tried this in Safari and Firefox as well, to see if the results are the same?

Comment: Yep. Works everywhere but Edge, and even work in Edge if the WebVTT files are served from the same source as the video.