# Datatables.js server side processing data doesn't load with microsoft edge

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I am currently working on a project using MVC5 and datatables.js.  I've configured data tables to fetch the data using serverside processing via a POST call to my web api.  Everything is working great in IE11, Firefox, Chrome, etc. However, when viewing using Microsoft Edge I get a blank table; no data is returned.  Using the network tab in the browser I can see that the AJAX call to my web API is never called.  I am using the newest version of datatables (1.10.15) I suspect the problem is something like this: [Microsoft Edge blocked cross-domain requests sent to IPs in same private network CIDR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581503/microsoft-edge-blocked-cross-domain-requests-sent-to-ips-in-same-private-network)

My web api controller and view with datatables is part of the same application/project.

Anyone have any ideas?

client side code:

```
$("#reviewTable").DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "info": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("GetReviews","api/Reviews")",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "ReviewName", "orderable": true },
                { "data": "Description", "orderable": true },
                { "data": "Type", "orderable": true },
                { "data": "CreatedDate", "orderable": true }
            ],
            "order": [[0, "asc"]],
            "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                $(row).attr("data-review-id", data.ID); 
            }
        });
```