# Microsoft EDGE Browser. Error SEC7117

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I open site https://www.1platforma.ru/ first time (or clean cache)
In developer console I see an error SEC7117.

[image: Screenshot]

MS EDGE Browser could not load bundle.min.css and bundle.min.js files.
How can my users open the site and see interface with CSS and JS if those files didn't load?..

Comment: Is this a programming-related question, or a question related to the browser program? Did you make the page you're trying to browse to?

Comment: I have this problem only in MS EDGE Broeser. It can't load bundle.min.css, bundle.min.js.

This site looks without styles http://take.ms/ojAdq

Yes, we are developers of this page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that those resouces are loaded from Intranet?

See here: [Understanding Enhanced Protected Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/03/23/understanding-enhanced-protected-mode/)

> Internet pages are not able to frame Intranet pages, load images or resources from them, send them CORS XHR requests, etc.

If that's the case, see my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32828629

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem was really in our Intranet Network... :)