# How to download the local storage text as a file from Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, microsoft-edge

I'm building my first Firefox extension. So far I am storing the
output in local storage, Now I want to download the storage data as a
.txt file. My javascript code is:

```
function saveRecordAsFile() {
   console.log("Record downLoad saveRecordAsFile---");
   if (localStorage.recordData) {
      recordArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.recordData);
      download(JSON.stringify(recordArr), fileNameJMX, 'text/plain');
   }
} 

function download(text, name, type) {   
   var a = document.createElement("a");
   var file = new Blob([text], { type: type });
   a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   a.download = name;  
   a.click();
}
```

This code works fine in chrome extension. Thanks in advance

Comment: So, is it related to Microsoft Edge as well? I notice you tagged it.

Comment: Yes, The Code should also work with Microsoft edge extension. Thanks

Comment: Is there any Javascript error?

Comment: I am getting "SEC7134: Resource 'blob:D772C9E1-7DD8-482B-8561-7D2BD96AA996' not allowed to load." exception.

Comment: It's related to CORS. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602343/microsoft-edge-browser-error-sec7117) as well.