# Microsoft Edge cannot reach VM with private IP

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-edge

I have a webserver running in an VM  (VirtualBox, configured with vagrant) which is assigned the private ip `10.0.0.20`. I can reach the webserver with Google Chrome, but not with Microsoft Edge. I have activated `Allow Localhost Loopback` in about:flags.

Does anybody what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you ever achieved a solution to this problem? (we are literally tearing our hair out with it)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the root cause of the problem, but here are some options to work around this:

1. Configure VM Networking to be **Bridged** rather than NAT;
2. Use a **proxy**, e.g. *Fiddler*;
3. **Port forward**, using `netsh`, `ssh` or other utilities.

For option 2 and 3, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42701618/3463091) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and can't find a workaroud -- even after 2 years.   I guess the final answer is: Stop using Edge.

Looks like Microsoft is dumping it: [https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/12/post-mortem-tying-edge-to-windows-10-was-a-fatal-error/]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the start menu and type "Internet Options" Select internet options and open he security tab click on Local Intranet then press the sites button.

Control Panel > Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet  > Sites

Uncheck "include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones" and "Include all sites that bypass the proxy server".

Restart Edge and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it didn't work. I can reach the site with Internet Explorer, regardless of the setting you mentioned, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine with the webserver has internet access you could use a tool like ngrok to create a tunnel with a public URL to your machine.

http://www.sitepoint.com/use-ngrok-test-local-site/

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the latest win 10 V 1809 build 17763.253.

I have checked several threads that don't show any solution, but I found one thread with a workaround by adding the local IP range to the trusted sites, it works for me.

Second workaround is using the server name instead of the IP address.

Example: http://Computer-name/  which gets resolved to IP version 6 address.

Since this is bug only happens with MS EDGE and works fine with all other browsers,  where is the official MS solution ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcePi.png)