# Microsoft Edge cannot connect to URLs that resolve to 127.0.0.1

Tags: microsoft-edge

I read that Edge cannot connect to http://localhost, but I've already solved that one using about:flags and "allow loopback" .. it doesnt solve my current problem though

My company has a domain `localhost.mycompany.com` that is set in DNS to resolve to 127.0.0.1
We use it because we have `login.mycompany.com` that sets a domain auth cookie, so when we're debugging on local machines, we can use the `login.mycompany.com` to set the cookie, then proceed to `localhost.mycompany.com:xxxx` (where x is a different port number depending on which web app we're debugging)

Has worked fine in all browsers over the years but I note that even though Edge will connect to `http://localhost:12345` it will not connect to `http://localhost.mycompany.com:12345` (which is vital for it to submit the cookie login.mycompany.com set)

What can I do to get Edge connecting to this address?

Answer (score 3):

In a related post [Why does Microsoft Edge open some local websites, but not others, where the domain name is routed to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384571/why-does-microsoft-edge-open-some-local-websites-but-not-others-where-the-doma) I found a DOS command snippet:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

Running this in an elevated CMD seems to have solved the problem