# Microsoft Edge: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, microsoft-edge

I have a single page html and Angularjs file.

App.js

```
angular
.module('vod', [])
.controller('moviesController', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.movies = [];
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/movies/').then(function (response) {
        self.movies = response.data;
    }, function (errResponse) {
        console.error('Error while fetching movies');
    });
}]);
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular</title>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="moviesController as ctrl"
          ng-app="vod">
        <div ng-repeat="movie in ctrl.movies">
            <span ng-bind="movie.title"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works well on Chrome producing the movie titles but gives the errors
`SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2, The system cannot find the file specified`
and
`SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.` on Microsoft Edge.

Comment: i have the same problem? solution?

Comment: I also have this problem

Comment: [Duplicate of a lot of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=XMLHttpRequest%3A+Network+Error+0x2efd%2C+Could+not+complete+the+operation+due+to+error+00002efd)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati)

Answer (score 3):

There are several things which can go wrong.

Try adding the `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8` header.

Edge does not like VPN and mixed networks. This is probably not the case for you, but good to know.

More to read:

1. [SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387)
2. [Why does Microsoft Edge open some local websites, but not others, where the domain name is routed to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384571)

Comment: thx for mentioning VPN, it probably saved the other half of the day looking for the problem

Comment: Could you please comment incase you figured the issue? I'm facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but maybe a fresh reply will help somebody learn in case similar problems are found today. In Windows 10 all modern apps runs in AppContainers that are forbidden by isolation rules to send network traffic to the local computer. Edge is regarded as a modern app as seen here:
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/11/microsoft-edge-building-a-safer-browser/

For purposes of development you may find tools like ngrok or loopback helpful. I am sure app isolation rules change over time so try to stay up to date with the current limits and realize you are running in an AppContainer if you are using the Edge browser.