# Angular 6 IE with Azure 11 XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied

Tags: azure, http-headers, angular6, cross-domain, azure-api-management

I have an angular app sending http post request to Azure apim.

It works fine in Chrome and FF but fails in IE 11. I have looked at other solutions but nothing worked.

CORS policy is set to allow all header and all methods.

I am getting this kind of error in IE network TAB.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.

I see GET request with 200 instead of POST, also there is nothing in the request and response headers.

[image]

Comment: Did you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40383565/1658906?

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14527387/1658906?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a Windows 10 bug in the HTTP stack that is now solved in Windows 10 version 1803 (April 2018). So normally this problem will disappear over time for people/companies using auto updates of Windows, used [Windows 10 versions WorldWide](https://reports.adduplex.com/#/r/2019-10).

We tested this on an older and newer version of Windows 10 and it is indeed solved.

Some [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049814/ie11-https-ajax-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2eff-could-not-complete-the-ope?answertab=votes#tab-top) could be:

1.Disable HTTP/2 for IE and Edge and use HTTPS (server side change).
2.Use GET (if possible)
3.Do PUT also has this problem?
4.Do some retries if no response headers are returned
5.Accept that IE/Edge users will be punished ;-)