# React. IE11 requests being blocked

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

Im testing my react app in IE11 but all the requests I make to my server are blocked.

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHTTPRequest: Network error 0x2efd, Couldnt complete the operation due a 00002efd error.
```

This happens when i try to do a post in a form.

Only happens in IE11.

I have already added IE11 Support adding this in index.tsx

```
import "react-app-polyfill/ie11";
```

I have already disabled browsers protected mode.

Comment: I recommend **strongly** not to think to deal with IE.

Comment: I had this issue earlier, try this -  https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/make-react-work-in-ie11/

Comment: Have you added this line `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>` in public/index.html? In my test, we need to add this line to make react app work in IE 11. Do you serve your app on localhost or on the Internet? From my research, the error might related with the network, you can change your network and test again. You can also refer to this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383565/microsoft-edge-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2efd-could-not-complete-the-ope).

Comment: Im servir it thru localhost , a local build i do, probably the error is related, but so far no luck fixing it @YuZhou

Comment: Can you please try to serve it on the Internet to see if it can fix the issue? If still can't, please provide a minimal code snippet which can **reproduce** the issue so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with IE11 being unable to read 3** codes. I had to chenge them all to 2**