# Can't access my local virtual-box hosted sites using Edge (works in Chrome/Firefox/IE11)

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, microsoft-edge

I am running Vagrant for our local web development sites, they all work fine on Chrome, Firefox and even Internet Explorer 11. However when using the Microsfot Edge browser I always get the following message:

```
Can't reach this page
```

Obviously this is something unique to Edge, can anyone guess to why this is happening?

I am running the following:

```
Vagrant 1.9.2
VirtualBox 5.1.2
Windows 10 Home
```

This happens if I enter the IP or the hostname

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Microsoft Edge open some local websites, but not others, where the domain name is routed to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384571/why-does-microsoft-edge-open-some-local-websites-but-not-others-where-the-doma)

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem, Vagrant site wouldnt load on Edge (site not found), but worked on Chrome, IE, Firefox, etc.

The workaround for me was changing the VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter’s "*NdisDeviceType" from 1 to 0 and rebooting:

1. open regedit
2. navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\00XX.
3. For me, the path to the registry key "*NdisDeviceType" ended with \0016
4. set "*NdisDeviceType" to 0
5. reboot

> The downside to this is that now you’ll have an “Unidentified Network”
>   in your Network and Sharing Center. It’s also managed by Windows
>   Firewall now and by default it is in the Public Profile and it can’t
>   be really changed easily.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10142843/#comment-8