# Edge + VPN + Fiddler

Tags: microsoft-edge, fiddler, vpn

While a VPN is enabled, Microsoft Edge stopped opening pretty much any URL after some or another recent Windows update.  The only solution that worked for me was to install Fiddler based on another question at this site.  Any idea why Edge requires a proxy server to again work while a VPN is enabled?

Sorry to be so vague on which Windows update I suspect started this issue.  Some time passed before both Edge and the VPN connection were both in use.

See:
[Edge Opens some sites and not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384571/why-does-microsoft-edge-open-some-local-websites-but-not-others-where-the-doma/37848210)

Answer (score -1):

If you had installed [January 8, 2019—KB4480966 (OS Build 17134.523)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4480966/windows-10-update-kb4480966) or [January 15, 2019—KB4480976 (OS Build 17134.556)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4480976/windows-10-update-kb4480976) than you may experience that you cannot load a webpage in Microsoft Edge using a local IP address. Browsing fails or the webpage may become unresponsive. This was considered as a known issue after these 2 updates.

Below steps can help you to fix this issue temporary.

(1) Open the Control Panel and select Internet Options.

(2) On the Security tab, select the Trusted Sites icon.

(3) Select the Sites button.

(4) Clear the check box for Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone.

(5) In the Add this website to the zone: box, type the local IP address that failed to load, such as http://192.168.0.1.

(6) Select the Add button.

(7) Select the Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone check box.
Select the Close button.

(8) Select the OK button.

(9) Restart Microsoft Edge.

Microsoft is working on a resolution and will provide an update in an upcoming release.

Comment: Sorry - solution did not work.  Issue is not with a 192 or any local IP address.  Issue is with pretty much all URLs (sites).  If a site is not in the list of trusted sites, it will not load.  The links from the email back to stackoverflow.com do not work.  Had to provide this update via Chrome.  Unsecured sites also do not work.

Comment: These are the symptoms regarding this issue. For testing purpose, Can you try to remove those updates to check whether it resolves your issue or not. Than we can accurately say that the issue caused by this update.

Comment: OS Versions is:   Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.292].  Neither of the patches mentioned appear to be installed when searching for KB4480966 and KB4480976 from the Control Panel > Programs and Features > Installed Updates.