# Unable to load local website inside Iframe in Edge

Tags: javascript, windows, iis, iframe, microsoft-edge

I've two sites site-1 (Parent) and site-2 (child). Both are hosted on two machines on IIS V10 (windows 10) on the same network. Site-2 is loaded inside site-1 using Iframe.

The site-2 is loaded in Iframe in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) but Edge. I get following error in Edge:
[image]

Here, I am using IP address and port for the site-2 in the iframe instead of the hostname.

Here is how I am creating Iframe in JS:

```
var elem = document.createElement("iframe");
elem.setAttribute("src", "http://172.18.48.43:5051/play/Web/21");
elem.setAttribute("id", "site-2");
elem.style.width = 800 + "px";
elem.style.height = 300 + "px";
elem.style.border = 1 + "px solid Orange";
var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
$("#frame").html(elem);
```

The Iframe works in edge in two conditions:

1. If both site-1 and site-2 are on the same machine.
2. If instead of IP, I use public domain hostname like http://www.some-domain.com

I tried following solutions, but nothing worked so far:

https://windowsreport.com/fix-hmm-we-cant-reach-this-page-edge/

https://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-hmm-we-cant-reach-this-page-error-in-microsoft-edge/

[Why does Microsoft Edge open some local websites, but not others, where the domain name is routed to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384571/why-does-microsoft-edge-open-some-local-websites-but-not-others-where-the-doma/37848210)

Comment: Perhaps the issue is the Edge browser setting, try to [reset the Edge browser setting](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/reset-microsoft-edge/). If still not working, try to add the IP address (http://172.18.48.43) into the [Trusted Sites Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6RYi.png).

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. You can try loading the iframe child-app (site 2) in another tab and refresh to see if the iframe will load accordingly. That works for us.