# How do I start my local IIS web app with Edge?

Tags: .net, iis, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to start a local .NET web application that runs on IIS in Microsoft Edge, but I constantly get the error message "Cannot reach this page". I can run the application in Chrome and IE. I have tried lots of mentioned solutions here on Stack Overflow and other websites but none of them have been helpful to me. I have tried to:

1. Check that my DNS Client is running.
2. Enable localhost loopback by navigating to *about:flags* in Edge.
3. Go to Internet Options>Security and add localhost as a trusted site, as well as checking the boxes in "Local intranet".

The application I work on has to function properly in Edge, so I really need to be able to test the application locally in Edge.

I would deeply appreciate any kind of help or feedback.

I went through all the solutions in this thread but none of them helped me.
[Can't open local iis site in ie edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563611/cant-open-local-iis-site-in-ie-edge/58609313)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1120029/microsoft-edge-can-not-display-local-web-site

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge version are you using? Please check the solution in these similar threads: [thread 1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0face535-3c7a-4658-be34-6c376322ca34/microsoft-edge-cant-open-local-domains?forum=win10itpronetworking), [thread 2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-browser-cant-access-network-ip/1e7d32c7-f8ed-431d-9b64-ed822dd28717) and [thread 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334289/cant-open-localhost-in-microsoft-edge-project-spartan-in-windows-10-preview).

Comment: If still not working, try to reset the [IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) and  [Microsoft Edge Browser Setting](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT The version I'm using is Microsoft Edge 44.18362.387.0.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I have tried all of the above but nothing worked. I even tried to repair, reset and reinstall Edge. I installed Fiddler but I couldn't get it to work with Edge.

Comment: Which windows version are you targeting?@Yamo93

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Windows 10.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT To be more precise: Windows 10 Pro version 18362.476.

Comment: @Yamo93, I tried to reproduce your environment to test this issue, but didn't roll back to your Edge version:44.18362.387.0 . Currently my lab OS is 18362.476 but edge version is 44.18362.449.0 . Could you please share your windows update KB list? I can adjust the KB to match your edge version. Thanks !

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT Excuse my ignorance, but how do you want me to share the list? I ran the command "dism /online /get-packages" in the command prompt. Do you want me to share a screenshot of that package list?

Comment: @Yamo93, You could post your KB list on public storage and share link to us if it didnt include any sensitive information. Also, you could try to update Edge to latest version  if the issue was not fixed when you have checked loopback feature on Edge

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT Here is my KB list: https://justpaste.it/3ph0m
I tried to update Edge and check the loopback feature but it didn't help.

Comment: @Yamo93, thanks for your response! I reinstalled these KB and make the same version of Edge. But I didn't reproduce the Localhost failed issue. Please check three option:<1>HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\ExperimentalFeatures\AllowLocalhostLoopback set value to 1  <2>[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\TabProcConfig]
 remove your IP

Comment: <3> change webdebugger settings to test this issue:https://ibb.co/q9Pv6F0

Comment: I tried the first option, but it was already set to 1. I tried the second option, but I couldn't even find the TabProcConfig in that directory. I tried the third option, but it didn't do any difference. 
By the way, in Fiddler I get this "lock sign" when I try to access that webpage from Edge:
https://ibb.co/Vp2H2sX

Comment: @Yamo93, httpstatus code 401 was shown your request didnt pass  authenticated from your fiddler image. Could you enable windows authorization on your site?

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT Windows Authentication is already enabled on the site.

Comment: @Yamo93,could you please share your fiddler  log with me ? I will help on analyze it

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT The Fiddler log doesn't say too much though. It seems that there is some configuration that needs to be changed in our application. Other developers have experienced the same problem. But thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: @Yamo93,Thanks for your response. You're welcome! :)